# Problema con install react-dom

Tags: reactjs

Bueno estaba viendo tutoriales sobre reactjs entonces instalando las dependecias he usado este comando

```
npm install react react-dom
```

pero al momento que deberia instalarlos me sale este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes cambiar la propiedad `name` de tu `package.json`, el error;

> **Refusing to install react as dependency of itself**

Significa que estás instalando un ***módulo*** dentro de una carpeta que se llama igual a dicho ***módulo*** o que la propiedad `name` de tu `package.json` es igual a un ***módulo instalado***, bastaría con cambiar lo dicho al principio y quizá el nombre de la carpeta del proyecto